# How can I use LatentSvmDetector / DPMDetector from OpenCV on nVidia GPU (CUDA or OpenCL)?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, svm

How can I use [LatentSvmDetector (OpenCV 2.4)](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/latent_svm.html#LatentSvmDetector) or the same [DPMDetector (OpenCV 3.0)](http://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dba/classcv_1_1dpm_1_1DPMDetector.html#details) on nVidia GPU (CUDA or OpenCL)?

There are only:

- [`cv::LatentSvmDetector`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/latent_svm.html#LatentSvmDetector) in OpenCV 2.4
- [`cv::dpm::DPMDetector`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dba/classcv_1_1dpm_1_1DPMDetector.html#details) in OpenCV 3.0

But nothing of these for namespace gpu::, cuda:: or ocl::.

For gpu there are only `gpu::HOGDescriptor` and `ocl::HOGDescriptor` but as I know it are not compatible with LatentSvmDetector/DPM.

I want to detect objects in real-time video on GPU by using these already trained model in [OpenCV 2.4](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_extra/tree/2.4.12.x-prep/testdata/cv/latentsvmdetector/models_VOC2007) or [OpenCV 3.0](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_extra/tree/master/testdata/cv/dpm/VOC2007_Cascade).

Comment: As far as I can see, [this is the best available](https://github.com/CPFL/Autoware/tree/master/ros/src/computing/perception/detection/lib/image/dpm_ocv/gpu), a port of that LatentSvmDetector to CUDA, but the implementation is pretty poor - each step of the pyramid is evaluated in serial, only processing each image is parallelised, so I'm not sure if there's much of a performance boost, as I haven't done comparative benchmarks.

Comment: I also found that for the above code, despite a LAMBDA of 10 being recommended by the literature, LAMBDA = 2 produced less false-positives for my dataset, and allowed real-time operation.

Comment: @Ken Y-N  Thank you! I'll try it.